# If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, $A^5=B^5$ then $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$, $B$ be **real symmetric** $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^5=B^5$.

Prove that $A=B$.

Here are my attempts:

The following identity holds $(A-B)(A^4+A^3B+A^2B^2+AB^3+B^4)=0$ and yields at least one non-invertible matrix. What to do with that ?

Since $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, they can be orthogonally diagonalized as $D_1$ and $D_2$. Moreover $D_1^5$ and $D_2^5$ are orthogonally similar. I'm stuck here.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Have you tried to prove that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes, I forgot about that ! What's for sure is that $A$ and $B^5$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, as well as $B$ and $A^5$. How would you prove that $A$ and $B$ commute ?

Comment: Better, yet, you can recover $A$ from $A^5$, as Yiorgos's answer points out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric, then it is orthogonally diagonalized is $A=U^*DU$, where $U^*U=I$ and 
$$
D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n),
$$
where the $d_i$'s are real.
Then
$A^5=U^*D^5U$.

If we know that $A$ is symmetric and we know $A^5$ we can UNIQUELY reproduce $A$ since
$$
A^5=U^*\mathrm{diag}(d_1^5,\ldots,d_n^5)U,
$$
and although the equation $x^5=d_j^5$ has five roos in general, only one of them if real.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Comment: I can't understand why the condition of symmetry implies we can reproduce $A$ starting from $U^*D^5U$. Could someone explain to me? thanks in advance

Comment: We can even assume that $A^5$ is diagonal, and $A$ is symmetric, and start from here.